# function for adding new contacts won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I watched a youtube video about coding in vanilla javascript because I'm currently studying javascript. I wanted to add an "adder" for names that start with letter `a`.

I wrote a `do1` function and I added `div` between all names that start with `a`. I don't know what's going on here to be host what's the problem. I'm currently moving from basics to intermediate level in javascript, I'm trying to practice my javascript skills in any possible way. function filter names was written by someone else. I don't have that much skills to do something like that.

So if you have any ideas on how should I practice js. If you have any websites or even tasks that could help me in learning javascript. would appreciate if you linked me any in comments section.

```js
let filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');

filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
  // Get value of input
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();

  // Get names ul
  let ul = document.getElementById('names');
  // Get lis from ul
  let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.collection-item');

  // Loop through collection-item lis
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    // If matched
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

}

function do1() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('ipt1').value;
  var item = document.createTextNode(input1);
  var li = document.createElement('li').className = "collection-header";
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var child1 = li.appendChild(a);
  var div = document.getElementById('div1');
  div1.appendChild(item).innerHTML = item;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.css">
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="center-align">
    My Contacts
  </h1>
  <input type="text" id="filterInput" placeholder="Search names...">
  <ul id="names" class="collection with-header">
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>A</h5> <input type="box" id="ipt1"> <button onclick="do1();">`click me to add another contact`</button>
    </li>


    <div id="div1">
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Abe</a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Adam</a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Alan</a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Anna</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>B</h5> <input type="box" id="ipt2">
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Beth</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Bill</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Bob</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Brad</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>C</h5> <input type="box" id="ipt3">
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Carrie</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Cathy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Courtney</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
let filterInput = document.getElementById("filterInput");

filterInput.addEventListener("keyup", filterNames);

function filterNames() {
  // Get value of input
  let filterValue = document.getElementById("filterInput").value.toUpperCase();

  // Get names ul
  let ul = document.getElementById("names");
  // Get lis from ul
  let li = ul.querySelectorAll("li.collection-item");

  // Loop through collection-item lis
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    // If matched
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function do1() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("ipt1").value;
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.textContent = input1;
  a.setAttribute('href', "#");
  var li = (document.createElement("li"));
  li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
 
  li.appendChild(a);
  var div = document.getElementById("div1");
  div1.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.css">
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="center-align">
    My Contacts
  </h1>
  <input type="text" id="filterInput" placeholder="Search names...">
  <ul id="names" class="collection with-header">
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>A</h5> <input type="box" id="ipt1"> <button onclick="do1();">`click me to add another contact`</button>
    </li>


    <div id="div1">
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Abe</a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Adam</a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Alan</a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="#">Anna</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>B</h5> <input type="box" id="ipt2">
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Beth</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Bill</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Bob</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Brad</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>C</h5> <input type="box" id="ipt3">
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Carrie</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Cathy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <a href="#">Courtney</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The issues you were having

```
  var item = document.createTextNode(input1); // this line was not needed as you already had the text

  var li = document.createElement('li').className = "collection-header"; // assigning a string here causing errors. Use setAttribute() not class name.

  div1.appendChild(item).innerHTML = item; assigning to innerHTML of appended child
```

so changing the function from:

```
function do1() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('ipt1').value;
  var item = document.createTextNode(input1);
  var li = document.createElement('li').className = "collection-header";
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var child1 = li.appendChild(a);
  var div = document.getElementById('div1');
  div1.appendChild(item).innerHTML = item;
}
```

to :

```
function do1() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("ipt1").value; // get the value of the input
  var a = document.createElement("a"); // create new a tag
  a.textContent = input1; // Set the text of the a tag
  a.setAttribute('href', "#"); // Set the href attribute of the a tag
  var li = (document.createElement("li")); // Create new list item
  li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item'); // Set class attribute of li tag
  li.appendChild(a); // Append the a tag to the list item
  var div = document.getElementById("div1"); // get the containing div
  div1.appendChild(li); // append the new list item to the div
}
```

Now you are able to append to the first div around A. To append to others, you first would need div tags with different ID's. Then you would just need to either create a new function for each one or pass which div ID you were calling the method on..

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following line of code:

```
var li = document.createElement('li').className = "collection-header";
```

This code assigns the string "collection-header" to the variable named `li`. Strings don't have the `appendChild` function, so your code is crashing on the line:

```
var child1 = li.appendChild(a);
```

Not sure what your intention is by using two `=` in the same line of code.  If you can explain that further, perhaps someone can help you achieve your desired result.

Comment: Also, `div1` is an ID and not a variable name.